# How to silence printf called from within a Ruby C extension?

Tags: c, ruby, printf, stdout

- I am running a Ruby gem which relies on a C extension (not a call to system).
- The C code makes several calls to printf.
- I want to silence the output of these calls.
- Changing Ruby's STDOUT ([example](http://eddymulyono.livejournal.com/65791.html)) or STDERR does not prevent the text from being output.

Is it possible to do this without modifying the C code? If so, how?

Comment: I remember failing to find a way to do this in the past.

Comment: When running your program, which of the command suffixes "2>/dev/null" and ">/dev/null" silences the offending `printf`s?  Also, which extension is it?

Comment: If redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` when you run `ruby` is not sufficient then there must be something special going on in the gem.  We'd have to see the source to know.  It seems unlikely that they are opening `/dev/tty` directly to get around `stdout/stderr` but that's the only thing I can think of if they are not inheriting stdio from ruby.

Comment: @WayneConrad, running ruby script.rb >/dev/null silences the output, while >2/dev/null does not.

Comment: @BenJackson, the gem in question is lda-ruby, v. 0.3.8. The offending line is in ext/lda-alpha.c, line 64, and it reads `printf("alpha maximization : %5.5f   %5.5f\n", f, df);`. Grepping the source code for 'tty' and for 'dev' yields no result.

Comment: @louism: Sounds like your previous comment (`... > /dev/null` silences the output) conflicts with the original problem bullet 4.  Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Ben Jackson, my goal was to silence a specific block of code instead of silencing the Ruby interpreter. I've now solved the problem, using IO.reopen as suggested by a previous commenter who unfortunately deleted his comment (see edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone originally commented on my post suggesting to use [IO.reopen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-reopen). This worked for me. The person has unfortunately since deleted his/her comment, so I'm posting the more detailed function I used in the end:

```
def silence_stdout(log = '/dev/null')
  old = $stdout.dup
  $stdout.reopen(File.new(log, 'w'))
  yield
  $stdout = old
end
```

Usage:

```
silence_stdout { foo }              # Won't be displayed, won't be logged.
silence_stdout('log.txt') { bar }   # Won't be displayed, logged in log.txt.
```

Comment: Note that /dev/null should be changed to NUL on Windows.

Comment: Is it possible save into string, not file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the C source code:

```
#define printf(...)
```

This macro form is a C99 variadic macro.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Ruby is printing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, which is why changing Ruby's `stdout` doesn't fix your problem.
(Both `stderr` and `stdout` typically go to the console.)

Try redirecting `stderr`.  As I recall it'd be: `myprogram 2> /dev/null`

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but unfortunately this fails as well.